# Integrating spring Websession with spring reactive web flux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

There is a new implementation of http session for spring new reactive web flux api located [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebSession.html#start--).
I would like to integrate the latest spring web session in the new spring reactive web flux. I can't seem to get it, I tried injecting it as a bean, but it does not work. I would like to inject it like I usually do with HttpSession

something like

```
@Autowired
Websession webSession;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Spring WebFlux is a reactive web framework, you can't expect the Web Session to be injected as a bean (even in the request scope). In the Servlet world, each request/response is processed in a single thread, which enables those approaches (i.e. the "request" scope). With WebFlux, a given request can be processed by multiple threads.

The `WebSession` instance associated with the current request/response is actually attached to the `ServerWebExchange` (see [getSession](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html#getSession--)). Because of the nature of the reactive programming model, you're very likely to access that session within a Reactor operator - so you can't expect to inject this instance somewhere else in your application.

Comment: i want to be able to set some parameters in the session object just like i use to with spring web mvc , but it seems this is not possible with web flux

Comment: that's a little vague; you can add attributes to a WebSession. Feel free to create a new question stating exactly what you'd like to do and what you've tried so far. Starting with the use case is usually a good way.