# spring webflux how to create session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In spring webflux, how to create session?
like this:

```
public void getTokenService(HttpSession httpSession) {
    httpSession.setAttribute("token", token);
}
```

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856486/integrating-spring-websession-with-spring-reactive-web-flux

Comment: i don`t know that means